# Marking an object as clean in SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy

Is there any way to explicitly mark an object as *clean* in the SQLAlchemy ORM?

This is related partly to a previous question on [bulk update strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870323/sqlalchemy-bulk-update-strategies).

I want to, within a `before_flush` event listener mark a bunch of object as actually not needing to be flushed. This is due to them being manually synced with the database by other means.

I have tried the strategy below, but it results in the object being removed from the session, which then can cause problems later when a lazy load happens.

```
@event.listens_for(SignallingSession, 'before_flush')
def before_flush(session, flush_context, instances):
    ledgers = []

    if session.dirty:
        for elem in session.dirty:
            if ( session.is_modified(elem, include_collections=False) ):
                if isinstance(elem, Wallet):
                    session.expunge(elem) # causes problems later
                    ledgers.append(Ledger(id=elem.id, amount=elem.balance))

    if ledgers:
        session.bulk_save_objects(ledgers)
        session.execute('UPDATE wallet w JOIN ledger l on w.id = l.id SET w.balance = l.amount')
        session.execute('TRUNCATE ledger')
```

I want to do something like:

```
session.dirty.remove(MyObject)
```

But that doesn't work as `session.dirty` is a computed property, not a regular attribute. I've been digging around the instrumentation code, but can't see how I might fool the `dirty` list to not contain something. I see there is also a `history` on the object state that will need taking care of as well.

Any ideas? The underlying database is MySQL if that makes any difference.

-Matt

Answer (score 2):

When you modify the database outside of the ORM, you can let the ORM know the current database state by using [`set_committed_value()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.set_committed_value).

Example:

```
wallet = session.query(Wallet).filter_by(id=123)
wallet.balance = 0
session.execute("UPDATE wallet SET balance = 0 WHERE id = 123;")
set_committed_value(wallet, "balance", 0)
session.commit()  # won't issue additional SQL to update wallet
```

If you *really* wanted to mark the instance as not dirty, you can muck with the internals of SQLAlchemy:

```
state = inspect(p)
session.identity_map._modified.discard(state)
state.modified = False
print(p in session.dirty)  # False
```

Comment: Alas that doesn't quite do what I want it to do, as if `wallet` is already in `session.dirty` by virtue of if having a new value assigned to it before, I want to *remove* it from the dirty list. If I use `set_committed_value()` then it changes the value, but the object remains on the dirty list.

Comment: @MattHamilton It remains on the dirty list, but `is_modified` will return `False`.

Comment: Ahhh right, thanks! So whilst it appears dirty, the flush actually has no work to do. A bit more digging through that method and what I've ended up with is:

`instance_state(obj).committed_state.clear()` to clear the state of the object

Comment: @MattHamilton If you actually don't care about the state on the object at all, you can simply do `session.expire(p)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize this insanity.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import attributes

attributes.instance_state(your_object).committed_state.clear()
```

Easy. (no)